# Dividing shapefile into specific grid in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, vector

How can I divide a shapefile into grids of 5km by 5km in ArcGIS? How can we use [fishnet](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-fishnet.htm) in this case?

Comment: Create a fishnet, intersect with your shapefile

Answer (score 1):

Fishnet is the tool to use.  The [Esri documentation for how fishnet works](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/how-create-fishnet-works.htm) provides significant detail on how to use the tool but plan to run a couple tests if it's your first time using it.

One good approach is to use the bottom left coordinate of your shapefile's bounding box for your *Fishnet Origin coordinate*, then choose a point directly above it (ie same longitude) to give you the *Y-axis coordinate*.  Finally, use your upper right bounding box coordinate for the *opposite corner of fishnet* and the other parameters will self-populate.

Comment: Actually, the bottom-left corner can't be assumed to be the best place to start. A lot depends on the geometry to be partitioned, and whether it is evenly divisible by 5km. Personal preference plays a role, too. Center the shape, in which case the area of overlap on all edges will be smaller? Fewest or most empty squares? There's a lot of options here.

Comment: Agreed @Vince, but given the dearth of details in the question, I thought this is a sufficient place to start.